# How to calculate byte size of file if I declared it indirectly(BufferedReader with pathname?) (Java 6)

Tags: java, file, stream, size

Hypothetically we have this line
`BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src.txt"));`

At opening and closure of file how to calculate its size (for example with `length()`)

`inStream.legth()` ? at a `System.out.println()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `length` method of the `File` class:

```
 File f = new File(fileName);
 System.out.println(f.length())
```

Please note that you can use the `f` in your `BufferReader` object too :

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
```

Comment: @niCk> `BufferedReader` is a wrapper for both `InputStreamReader` and `FileReader, which buffers the information each time a native I/O is called.

Comment: @niCk> `f.length()` not `br`.

Comment: just add this: String fileName = "src.txt"; and then use the lines that I've shown in my answer.